# How I can create a matrix template for checking sentences similarity?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm new to text mining and python and I'm trying to do a simple task.
I want to create TF matrix from sentences:
['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence', 'This is the third sentence']

And in loop (or somehow) compare new sentences with this matrix.

On Stack Overflow I've found a good example which works fine, but in my case it would calculate TF matrix for sample sentences and new sentences each time. It will work a bit slow on large datasets.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
text = []
text = ['This is the first sentence','This is the second sentence', 'This is the third sentence']
text.append('new sentence')
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(text)

# Get an array of results
results = ( tfidf * tfidf.T ).A
```

I want to know how to do it in other more accurate way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can first do fit on original sentences

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
text = ['This is the first test ','This is the sentence', 'this is a third sentence']
vect.fit(text)

tfidf = vect.transform(text).A
>>> tfidf
array([[0.55249005, 0.32630952, 0.        , 0.55249005, 0.42018292,
    0.        , 0.32630952],
   [0.        , 0.43370786, 0.55847784, 0.        , 0.55847784,
    0.        , 0.43370786],
   [0.        , 0.39148397, 0.50410689, 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.66283998, 0.39148397]])
```

Then use it to transform the new ones:

```
new = vect.transform(['this sentence 1','new sentence 2']).A
>>> new
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.78980693, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.61335554],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        ]])
```

And then use some distance metric to compute similarity between sentences:

```
import scipy
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(tfidf, new, 'euclidean')
array([[1.26479741, 1.41421356],
       [0.76536686, 0.93970438],
       [0.85056925, 0.99588464]])
```